# Flutter App: How to build for testflight from visual studio code

Tags: ios, flutter, build

I am building my Flutter App in Visual Studio code and want to upload it to TestFlight. How do I generate a build that I can add and give to testers? Thank you for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/ios for more details.

There are many steps. You need to have Apple developers account, and enrolled too.

Answer (score 0):

As far my experience with iOS development and flutter, you need to have Xcode and Xcode team registered, and to deploy to TestFlight you need to build the archive of the iOS and deploy it with Xcode only.

https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/ios

Try to install Xcode on macOS susomi VM, and have apple developer account